Running `npm install expo-dev-client` makes it so that the development server no longer works?
I created a Blank Typescript template and ran npx expo start --tunnel, selected the development server from my Expo app on my phone. No issues. However, after running npm install expo-dev-client and starting the server again I could no longer open the server from my phone.
Running from WSL2 and using an Android phone
Any ideas what went wrong? Opening development servers from my phone used to be fine a few days ago, traced the problem to this.
